# How can i add fonts to windows fonts folder using advanced installer?

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

I want to add fonts to windows fonts folder when i install setup file using advanced installer.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If creating an MSI package, you can register a Font by taking these steps:

- add the Font in the **Files and Folders** page.
- double click it or from the context menu select “**Properties**”.
- select the **Registration** Tab.
- enable the "**Register font**" checkbox.
- write the "Registration Name" **only if** the font is not True-Type.

Advanced Installer also offers support to install fonts from MSIX package. To install the font by an MSIX you need to add your font file in "**Files and Folders**" and create an install font declaration for the MSIX package.

To create the font declaration Go to Universal Windows > Declarations, right-click on the application entry and select Add Application Declaration > Shared Fonts.

Press New > [...] to select and add your font as a shared font.

Please keep in mind that when installing the font by the MSIX, the fonts are installed per user not per-machine, meaning **only the user that installed the MSIX has access to them**.